# MySQL - Averaging values from two possible columns

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID      SCORE     OVERRIDE_SCORE
1       15        NULL
2       16        17
3       16        NULL
```

I am averaging the scores using:

```
SELECT AVG(SCORE) FROM QA
WHERE SCORE is not NULL
```

I would like to use the OVERRIDE_SCORE as the SCORE so that when the override score was present, the average would use that value instead of the value in SCORE.

Is that possible in a query?

Comment: Yes its possible

Comment: `AVG(COALESCE(OVERRIDE_SCORE, SCORE))`

Comment: Brilliant, thank you @barmar